# Shark bite vs shark bitten

Tags: expressions

During reading the book I happend to see shark bite . Is shark bite  spoken ecpressio  or idiom ? If I say shark bitten does it sound weird or wrong ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

*Shark bite* is a noun, and something you can *have* (or *give* if you are a shark).  This is communicating something that exists on your body or would exist on your body, or other object.

*Shark bitten* is a participle adjective, and is something you can *be*.  This is communicating something that has happened.

*Shark bite/bitten* is not an idiom/expression and means literally what it says AFAIK.